# error WIX0094: The identifier 'Binary:Wix4UtilCA_X86' could not be found

Tags: wix4

After this was fixed:
https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/7139

I pulled the github source and compiled it, but still get an error for the Custom Actions regarding the Binary Reference:

error WIX0094: The identifier 'Binary:Wix4UtilCA_X86' could not be found. Ensure you have typed the reference correctly and that all the necessary inputs are provided to the linker.

This is the XML Code:

```
        <CustomAction Id="RegisterPSCmd" Property="RegisterPowerShellProperty" Value="&quot;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&quot; -NoLogo -NonInteractive -InputFormat None -NoProfile -File &quot;C:\Windows\PCache\WSA0727-Notepad++_8.4.1_G\Deploy-Application.ps1&quot; &quot;-DeploymentType Install&quot;" Execute="immediate" />

        <CustomAction Id="RegisterPSCmdUninstall" Property="RegisterPowerShellPropertyUninstall" Value="&quot;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&quot; -NoLogo -NonInteractive -InputFormat None -NoProfile -File &quot;C:\Windows\PCache\WSA0727-Notepad++_8.4.1_G\Deploy-Application.ps1&quot; &quot;-DeploymentType Uninstall&quot;" Execute="immediate" />

        <CustomAction Id="RegisterPowerShellProperty" DllEntry="WixQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" BinaryRef="Wix4UtilCA_X86" />

        <CustomAction Id="RegisterPowerShellPropertyUninstall" DllEntry="WixQuietExec64" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" BinaryRef="Wix4UtilCA_X86" />
```

I tried to build with "-ext WixUtilExtension.dll" but it said that it doesn't find the DLL.

Comment: You don't appear to be asking for help fixing your own code, but asking whether you should raise an issue or wait for the next release. You need to make your own decision on that. Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: Np if my own code is wrong then i would be happy for any suggestion to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WixUtilExtension.dll has been replaced by NuGet package WixToolset.Util.wixext in WiX v4. Use a `PackageReference` with an explicit `Version`.

Comment: Thanks it worked referencing "-ext .\WixToolset.Util.wixext.dll"! :-)